# About loading spring beans, How to catch the bean that is loaded at first?

Tags: spring

I made some logic making db instance and create schema and tables for running.
And those logic is included in the web application file (war).  If I put the war into a specific container and then start the servlet container for loading the web application context, I want to run this logic whenever the instance is not created. How can I achieve this? please give some elaborate explanations..

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of [ServletContainerInitializer.onStartUp](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html#onStartup(java.util.Set,%20javax.servlet.ServletContext)) if you are on **Servlet 3.x** or use [ServletContextListener.contextInitialized](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized(javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent)) if on **Servlet 2.x**.

Within the implementation of the respective method invoke the custom setup you like to perform *before* initialization / start of the web app.

For code sample(s) see [here](http://javaevangelist.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/java-ee-7-tip-of-day-web-application.html).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But in my case,  I am using gretty gradle plugin for making war file and playing a role as a servlet container. I confirmed that META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer that has implemnation classes in the war. But the servlet container didn't regcognize the ServletContainerInitialzer.